# List all open Excel files so user may select a file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from an old file to a new file.

I have code that copies my data. The name of the old file and new file changes and I have to change that in my code every time.

Is there a way, I can get a list of open Excel files and select the file from which I want the data and the file to which I want to copy the data?

```
Sub Copy_rental()

Dim PYFILE As String
Dim CYFILE As String
Dim Columnstocopy As String

PYFILE = "Pro-invest HIE ADL Trust -  2018 WP.XLSX"
CYFILE = "Pro-invest HIE ADL Trust -  2019 WP.XLSX"

Columnstocopy = "C"

Windows(PYFILE).Activate
Sheets("Rental Schedule").Select
Range(Columnstocopy & "10:" & Columnstocopy & "14").Select
Selection.Copy

Windows(CYFILE).Activate
Sheets("Rental Schedule").Select
Range(Columnstocopy & "10").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Windows(PYFILE).Activate
Sheets("Rental Schedule").Select
Range(Columnstocopy & "16:" & Columnstocopy & "24").Select
Selection.Copy

Windows(CYFILE).Activate
Sheets("Rental Schedule").Select
Range(Columnstocopy & "16").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Windows(PYFILE).Activate
Sheets("Rental Schedule").Select
Range(Columnstocopy & "26:" & Columnstocopy & "27").Select
Selection.Copy

Windows(CYFILE).Activate
Sheets("Rental Schedule").Select
Range(Columnstocopy & "26").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
   
Windows(PYFILE).Activate
Sheets("Rental Schedule").Select
Range(Columnstocopy & "29").Select
Selection.Copy

Windows(CYFILE).Activate
Sheets("Rental Schedule").Select
Range(Columnstocopy & "29").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

EDIT: Thanks to the tip I am using this code to get the list of the open Excel files but it does not appears to working. VBA is also not throwing any error. Could this be because I have made the Userform on my personal.xlsb workbook?

The same code in the newblankworkbook it appears to be working.

```
Private Sub Onesource_copy_data_Initialize()

Dim wkb As Workbook

Me.Onesource_ComboBox1_oldfile.Clear
For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
    Me.Onesource_ComboBox1_oldfile.AddItem wkb.Name
Next wkb

Me.Onesource_ComboBox1_newfile.Clear
For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
    Me.Onesource_ComboBox1_oldfile.AddItem wkb.Name
Next wkb

End Sub
```

EDIT 2: I think the issue was `Onesource_copy_data_Initialize`. I should have left it as `UserForm_Initialize`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim wkb As Workbook

Me.Onesource_ComboBox_oldfile.Clear
For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
    Me.Onesource_ComboBox_oldfile.AddItem wkb.Name
Next wkb

Me.Onesource_ComboBox_newfile.Clear
For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
    Me.Onesource_ComboBox_newfile.AddItem wkb.Name
Next wkb

End Sub
```

EDIT3: I have made a combobox and it is working.

Code for Combobox

```
Private Sub Onesource_Copy_Cancel_CommandButton_Click()
Stopped = True
Unload Me
End Sub


Public Sub Onesource_Copy_Start_CommandButton_Click()

PYFILE = Me.Onesource_ComboBox_oldfile.Value
CYFILE = Me.Onesource_ComboBox_newfile.Value
' Calling Macro
Call Test123

Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim wkb As Workbook

Me.Onesource_ComboBox_oldfile.Clear
For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
    Me.Onesource_ComboBox_oldfile.AddItem wkb.Name
Next wkb

Me.Onesource_ComboBox_newfile.Clear
For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
    Me.Onesource_ComboBox_newfile.AddItem wkb.Name
Next wkb

End Sub
```

Start of the Excel code

Declaring the variable as public as this would be required

```
Public PYFILE As String

Public CYFILE As String

Sub Copy_PreTemplate_to_NewTemplate()
'
' Copy previous Template data to new Template
'
Onesource_Copy_form.Show

End Sub


Sub Test123()

Windows(PYFILE).Activate
Sheets("Non-numeric details").Select
Range("C6:C10").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows(CYFILE).Activate
Sheets("Non-numeric details").Select
Range("C6").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create userform for such a selection. Another option would be to use `InputBox` method. Here is a demonstration code.

```
Dim wkbSrc As Workbook, wkbDst As Workbook
Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range
Set rngSrc = Application.InputBox("Select Source Workbook", "Select Workbook", , , , , , 8)
Set rngDst = Application.InputBox("Select Destination Workbook", "Select Workbook", , , , , , 8)
Set wkbSrc = rngSrc.Parent.Parent
Set wkbDst = rngDst.Parent.Parent
```

Comment: This helps but the issue then will be that the name of the files has been exactly the same. I have explored the Userform options and I have written some code but for some reason Combo box is not adding anything in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If the sheet don't change position you can use their numeric indexes instead of sheet names:

```
Sheets(0).Select
```

If the sheets do change position iterate through all sheets looking for certain text to indicate which sheet is what.

Otherwise maintain a map of the possible names.

> This isn't really a programming problem, it's a problem around the process. A better solution is don't rename the sheets or use a Naming Convention such as sheetName-YYYYMMDD.

Comment: I see what you mean. That for letting me know. I am a newbie so these tips help

Comment: Tip: instead of Copy/Pasting simply assign the values across sheets:  `Worksheets(1).Cells.Range("A1").Value = Worksheets(2).Cells.Range("B2").Value`

Answer (score 1):

Try the next way, please:

```
Sub testSelectOpenWorkbook()
  Dim w As Workbook, wbCopy As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook, i As Long, strWb As String
  Dim chooseW As String
  
  For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count
    strWb = strWb & i & " - " & Workbooks(i).Name & vbCrLf
  Next
   chooseW = InputBox("Please choose the number in front of the Workbook to copy data" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strWb, _
            "Workbook to copy data selection", 1)
   If chooseW = "" Then MsgBox "You did not choose anything...": Exit Sub
   If Not IsNumeric(chooseW) Then
      MsgBox "You must write the number in front of the workbook name...":Exit Sub
   End If
   Set wbCopy = Workbooks(CLng(chooseW))
   Debug.Print wbCopy.Sheets.Count, wbCopy.Name
   
   'Please, proceed in exactly the same way to select the destination workbook
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good work around. I think I can get it working but a Userform approach will look more clean

Comment: @Ankit Kulshrestha: And where is the problem? If you input the workbooks name in a combo box, you can use it like `Set wbCopy = Workbooks(combo.value)`. What is not clear in this approach? Should I post such a code working for combo loading and workbook object defining?

Comment: There is no problem here. Actually, I like the idea of combo box more. Thanks for your help. I nearly there